# Normalization into three tables in postgres incl one association table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have original data like so:

```
foo     bar    baz    
1        a      b      
1        x      y      
2        z      q
```

And I want to end up with three tables, of which `I` and `III` are the main tables and `II` is an association table between `I` and `III`

I. e.:

`I`

```
id        foo
1          1
2          2
```

`II`

```
id        I_id     III_id
1          1         1
2          1         2
3          2         3
```

NB that I_ID is a serial and not foo

`III`

```
id        bar     baz
1          a       b
2          x       y
3          z       q
```

How would I go about inserting this in one go?

I have played around with CTEs but I am stuck at the following: if I start with `III` and then return the ID's I cannot see how I can get back to the `I` table since there is nothing connecting them (yet)

My previous solutions have ended up in pre-generating id sequences which feels so-so

Comment: Huh?  This new data format doesn't make sense to me.  Why do you need both II and III ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there is some polymorphism going on here that I have abstracted away

Answer (score 0):

What if you generate a dense rank ?

you generate first a big table with the information you need.

```
select foo, 
bar, 
baz,
dense_rank() over (order by foo) as I_id,
dense_rank() over (order by bar, baz) as III_id,
row_number() over (order by 1) as II_id
from main_Table
```

Then you just have to transfer in the table you want with a distinct.

Comment: I think this is basically what I am doing now. How would you approach offsetting the primary keys / serials of `I` and `III`?

Comment: is it a one time migration or a regular process? this method works perfectly for one time migration only.

Comment: ah yes, it's a regular process.

Comment: for me, regular process means 2 things. first a migration, you use this method. then a regular feeding of your 3 new tables, do you use ETL or scripts? just check if key exists in the table, and if not, increase by one the max.

Answer (score 0):

Start with "main" tables, create two main entities and then use their IDs to insert a record to "connection table" between them, you can use CTE for that of course (I assume that "main" tables I and III have `default nextval(..)` in PK column, pooling next ID from sequences):

```
with ins1 as (
  insert into tabl1(foo)
  values(...)
  returning *
), ins3 as (
  insert into tabl3(bar, baz)
  values (.., ..)
  returning *
)
insert into tabl2(i_id, ii_id)
select ins1.id, ins3.id
from ins1, ins3 -- implicit CROSS JOIN here:
                -- we assume that only single row was 
                -- inserted to each "main" table
                -- or you need Cartesian product to be inserted to `II`
returning *
;
```

Comment: how would this be done when I have mutiple rows in `III` for every row in `I`?

Comment: It depends on what you need. If you need to save ALL possible connections between rows in `I` and rows in `III`, then just use the query above (it is implicit `CROSS JOIN`, which will make the Cartesian product, so for `N` rows in one table and `M` rows in the second it will give you `N * M` connections to save to table `II`).  If you need something different, then please define how you see connections between those two tables, how to reduce the Cartesian product to something different – you need some condition to use in `JOIN` and in this case you will save less than `N * M` rows to `II`.

Comment: So, the phrase "mutiple rows in III for every row in I" makes me feel that there is something common that row in `I` has and also corresponding rows in `III` – this should allow you to write proper `JOIN` between `ins1` and `ins2` in the query above. That "common thing" is what allows to say "corresponding". What is it exactly – totally hidden in your question :)